# ActionCollection of Blend custom Behavior is always empty

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone, expression-blend

I have created Blend behavior, but when I add children to it in xaml, they does not appear in the collection. What might be the reason of that ?

When app is running, Actions collection does not contain any action, though it certainly should.

```
<Helpers:EnterKeyUpEventBehavior>
    <Helpers:CloseFlyoutAction />
</Helpers:EnterKeyUpEventBehavior>


[ContentProperty(Name = "Actions")]
class EnterKeyUpEventBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActionsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Actions", typeof (ActionCollection), typeof (EnterKeyUpEventBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(ActionCollection)));

    public ActionCollection Actions
    {
        get
        {
            var actions =  (ActionCollection) GetValue(ActionsProperty);
            if (actions == null)
            {
                actions = new ActionCollection();
                base.SetValue(ActionsProperty, actions);
            }
            return actions;
        }
        set { SetValue(ActionsProperty, value); }
    }


    private TextBox _associatedTextBox;
    public DependencyObject AssociatedObject
    {
        get { return _associatedTextBox; }
    }

    public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
    {
        _associatedTextBox = associatedObject as TextBox;
        if(_associatedTextBox == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("This Behavior only works with TextBox control!");
        _associatedTextBox.KeyUp += _associatedTextBox_KeyUp;
        Actions = new ActionCollection();
    }

    void _associatedTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            Interaction.ExecuteActions(_associatedTextBox, Actions, null);
        }
    }

    public void Detach()
    {
        _associatedTextBox.KeyUp -= _associatedTextBox_KeyUp;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use your behavior in the markup? And it doesn't seem right that you do not derive from `Behavior<TAttachmentTarget>`.

Comment: There is markup code above c# code. And in Windows phone there is only IBehavior interface, there is no Behavior class

Comment: Your property initialization looks suspicious, I would always do this in the ctor, see my answer (comming soon).

Comment: Does this fix your problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not;/

Comment: Ok, I have another idea... see my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionCollection Actions
{
    get { return (ActionCollection) GetValue(ActionsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ActionsProperty, value); }
}

public EnterKeyUpEventBehavior()
{
    Actions = new ActionCollection();
}
```

The xaml parsing and instatiation mechanism does not use your getter and setter, it uses GetValue(ActionsProperty) and SetValue(ActionsProperty) directly, circumventing your "lazy init".

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when I want to use a collection type property as `ContentProperty` I have to either use a plain `List` or a `DependencyObjectCollection` (this is needed when you want the DataContext inheritance mechanism to function properly).

either:

```
public List<Action> Actions
{
    get { return (List<Action>) GetValue(ActionsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ActionsProperty, value); }
}

public EnterKeyUpEventBehavior()
{
    Actions = new List<Action>();
}
```

or:

```
public DependencyObjectCollection Actions
{
    get { return (DependencyObjectCollection) GetValue(ActionsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ActionsProperty, value); }
}

public EnterKeyUpEventBehavior()
{
    Actions = new DependencyObjectCollection();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but problem lied somewhere else, it appeares, that I was creating ActionCollection in Attach method, which was overriding that actioncollection which contained Actions. Thanks again, if it wasn't for You, I would have given up long ago!